# How does one reference another sheet using a string from another cell?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup, google-sheets-formula

This doesn't seem to work for me:

```
VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT(A4&"!")A1:Z40,5)
```

What can I change?

I get a formula parse error. I have fiddled around with quotes and such in the INDIRECT function, but it isnt working to draw the text "Arizona" I want from A4 to search a sheet called "Arizona" for a line with "Arizona"

Comment: Do you get an error message?  What specifically happens that "doesn't work"?  Please provide more details.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do google sheets formulae count as on-topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: @kristianp Yes, it count as on-topic. This was already discussed on [meta].

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, there seem to be some q&a on meta that imply it's on topic. e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332915/formatting-for-q-a-about-spreadsheet-cells-and-cell-functions

Comment: @kristianp There are other threads that explicitly discuss this.

Comment: @kristianp ...like this one [Are Excel formulas on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/1595451) (despite the title mentions Excel it could be extended to any spreadsheet application)

Comment: ok cool, I didn't find those ones!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `INDIRECT(A4&"!")A1:Z40`

Replace it with

`INDIRECT(A4&"!A1:Z40")`